# Can the Entity Framework be used from with a Windows 8 Windows Store app?

Tags: entity-framework, windows-8

Can a Windows 8 modern app (Metro app) utilize the Entity Framework with an embedded database?  If not, is there a better means to access and store structured data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is *"Windows 8 Modern app"*? Do you mean normal desktop/service/web application? In such case the answer is yes. Do you mean Metro style application? In such case the answer is no.

Comment: Microsoft had previously been calling apps build for the Metro UI 'modern apps'.  It appears to be disappearing from MSDN in favor of 'Metro Apps'

Comment: And now they are calling them 'Windows Store' apps.  Title updated accordingly.